# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined - Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I'm a noob in Dialogflow.

I am trying to access parameters from previous intent in follow up intent. Getting the above error

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined**
    at final (/srv/index.js:29:33)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:313:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:56:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

**Raw response**

```
{
  "responseId": "e2434e8b-92a4-41aa-9ff1-acf54003e262-ce609cdc",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "yes",
    "action": "TRansferthiscall.TRansferthiscall-yes",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Booking confirmed for 8784549879",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Booking confirmed for 8784549879"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/car-wninbg/agent/sessions/f35d3c8e-b572-387d-d185-53e46c73e65b/contexts/transferthiscall-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
          "phonenumber": "8784549879",
          "phonenumber.original": "8784549879"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/car-wninbg/agent/intents/b3cffc67-fd3c-44a3-8f26-c59234ddbe8c",
      "displayName": "TRansfer this call - yes"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 546
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  },
  "outputAudio": "/qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
  "outputAudioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_MP3",
    "synthesizeSpeechConfig": {
      "speakingRate": 1,
      "pitch": 4,
      "voice": {
        "name": "en-US-Wavenet-C"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Fulfillment request**

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d
>   '{"responseId":"e2434e8b-92a4-41aa-9ff1-acf54003e262-ce609cdc","queryResult":{"queryText":"yes","action":"TRansferthiscall.TRansferthiscall-yes","parameters":{},"allRequiredParamsPresent":true,"fulfillmentText":"Booking
>   confirmed for
>   8784549879","fulfillmentMessages":[{"text":{"text":["Booking confirmed
>   for
>   8784549879"]}}],"outputContexts":[{"name":"projects/car-wninbg/agent/sessions/f35d3c8e-b572-387d-d185-53e46c73e65b/contexts/transferthiscall-followup","lifespanCount":4,"parameters":{"phonenumber":"8784549879","phonenumber.original":"8784549879"}},{"name":"projects/car-wninbg/agent/sessions/f35d3c8e-b572-387d-d185-53e46c73e65b/contexts/**system_counters**","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0}}],"intent":{"name":"projects/car-wninbg/agent/intents/b3cffc67-fd3c-44a3-8f26-c59234ddbe8c","displayName":"TRansfer
>   this call -
>   yes"},"intentDetectionConfidence":1,"languageCode":"en"},"originalDetectIntentRequest":{"payload":{}},"session":"projects/car-wninbg/agent/sessions/f35d3c8e-b572-387d-d185-53e46c73e65b"}'
>   https://us-central1-car-wninbg.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

**CODE**

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
const axios = require('axios');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);

  }
     function call_final(agent) {
     const phonenumber = agent.parameters.phonenumber;
       agent.add(phonenumber + `Is your number correct?` );

  }
    function final(agent) {


      const context = agent.context.get('TRansferthiscall-followup');
    const phonenumber = context.parameters.phonenumber;

    agent.add(`Yaayyyyy!!!!!!! `+ phonenumber);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  function booking(agent) {
    const time = agent.parameters.time;
    const date = agent.parameters.date;
    const url ='http://klucky796.pythonanywhere.com/poc?NAME=test&phonenumber=14487&time='+ time+'&date=' + date;
    return axios.get(url)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
       agent.add(result.data);
    });

  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('BOOKING TIME DATE', booking);
  intentMap.set('TRansfer this call - yes', final);
  intentMap.set('TRansfer this call', call_final);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is due to the context name. The context in the raw JSON is `transferthiscall-followup`; however, in the code, you're retrieving it as:

```
const context = agent.context.get('TRansferthiscall-followup');
const phonenumber = context.parameters.phonenumber;
```

If the `context.get()` doesn't match it will stay as undefined and in the phonenumber line you'll try to read parameters from undefined.

Try changing the context.get() line to:

```
const context = agent.context.get('transferthiscall-followup');
```

Comment: God Dammit! I was stuck here since 3 days. Stupid me.

Comment: Glad to help! I've always thought that this kind of errors is one of the most hard to troubleshoot. I found that [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) works great for me in these situations.